# Android setOnClick not working/Dialogbox not appearing

Tags: android, onclick, dialogfragment

App launches fine but when I click on the Select_Players button, the Dialog box doesn't appear on my device. 
Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button selectPlayers;

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

            super.onStart();    //customize
            super.onResume();   //customize

            selectPlayers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_players);

            selectPlayers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // Launch dialogbox on click
                    onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

                }
            });
        }

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            final ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // Set the dialog title
            builder.setTitle(R.string.select_players)

            // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
            // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.players_name, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                        mSelectedItems.add(which);
                    } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                        // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                        mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }
                }
            })

            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    //CODE TO CLOSE DIALOGBOX AND START FORGE

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    //CODE TO JUST CLOSE DIALOGBOX

                }
            });

            return builder.create();
        }
}
```

I see that the Dialog method returns a Dialog but I'm not sure how to make it appear as a result of an onClick?  (for reference, I took the Dialog method from the Android dev. website.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This method returns a dialog , so You have to build one like this in Your onClick

```
     Dialog d = onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
     d.show();
```

I think what You had tried is to override the Activity method onCreateDialog(), but You have to do it in antoher way, like shown here:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-alertdialog-example-showdialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
selectPlayers.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Launch dialogbox on click
                onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

            }
        });
```

Always use the Listeners inside the View Extending object.
I changed in your code "View" to "Button" nothing more.
I haven't tested it yet and i remember to do it like you a lot and it worked. But i remember a problem of the last days depending the way android API handels inline listeners in Week Hashmaps, which get garbadge collected.
If this is your problem the solution is very simple.
Attach your listener to a variable and pass that variable.

Example:

```
Button.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Launch dialogbox on click
                onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

            }
        }; 
selectPlayers.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

This way your activity holds the listener and passing its instance to the button. Now the garbage collector should not remove it, till your activity is removed or you remove it manually.

Oh..
Haven't seen your call to "onCreateDialog". First methods which start with "on" are lifecycle methods, which will be called from the system not manually. Then onCreateDialog is deprecated i think. For this problem i refer to the answer of Opiatefuchs.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing show() function you should use like following...

dialog.show();

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the listener to the button in the onCreate().

```
private Button selectPlayers;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

    super.onStart();    //customize
    super.onResume();   //customize

    selectPlayers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_players);
    //set the listener to the button
    selectPlayers.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

Your code for your dialog box.

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    final ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_players)

    // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
    // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
    .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.players_name, null,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                mSelectedItems.add(which);
            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it 
                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
            }
        }
    })

    // Set the action buttons
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            //CODE TO CLOSE DIALOGBOX AND START FORGE

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            //CODE TO JUST CLOSE DIALOGBOX

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show(); 

}
```

Having one onClick() method means you can handle many buttons etc with one method, using an if/case statement to differentiate each one, here if the arg0 is the button that is used to call the dialog then it should call the method that handles your dialog box.

```
public void onClick(View arg0)
{  
        if(arg0== selectPlayers){
         //Show your dialog
 }
}
```

This is personal preference doing it this way, I feel it keeps everything tidy and together but again its just my opinion.